# Powershell script works with Add-AzureAccount but not Login-AzureRmAccount

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

I have a zip file that contains the azure functions to be deployed to the function app that I previously deployed via a Powershell script.

I don't have any of my own Azure Subscription's. I wrote a piece of code which works fine when you are the owner of the subscription, I want the same functionality to be able to done without the owner subscription thing.

If I do `Login-AzureRmAccount`, this script is not working. It's working only for `Add-AzureAccount`..

```
Add-AzureAccount
Get-AzureSubscription -Current
$subscriptionName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter target Subscription name'
Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
$FuncAppName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Function App Name you provided in above step'
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Package "Kovai.AtomicScope.Azure.zip" -Name $FuncAppName
```

Comment: There is no cmdlet as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that there is no `Publish-AzureRMWebsiteProject` cmdlet (there is a `Select-AzureRmSubscription` cmdlet that gets you a bit closer, but not all the way).

However, publish-AzureWebsiteProject is a wrapper over [Web Deploy\MSDeploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy), so you could use msdeploy directly. You can also use [WAWSDeploy](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/03/WAWSDeploy.html) (also a wrapper around msdeploy), which should make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The Publish* cmdlet is a really old Azure RDFE cmdlet.  Login-AzureRMAccount is an Azure Resource Manager (i.e. newer) cmdlet.

Essentially, the Azure and AzureRM cmdlets talk to different endpoints and require different authentication.  That's not 100% true (there are a few exceptions) but that's what's happening in this case.

So if the cmdlet you're using is Verb-AzureSomething, you need Add-AzureAccount.  If the cmdlet is Verb-AzureRM* then you need to authenticate with Login-AzureRMAccount of Add-AzureRMAccount.